Keyboard stops working after opening the laptop lid
I started using Ubuntu recently, and I'm facing an annoying problem when opening laptop's lid after closing it without shutting down or suspending the laptop. The problem is the built-in keyboard stops working completely, and I need to plug in another keyboard to be able to log in again. The mousepad works perfectly without any problems.
Device details:
   Lenovo Ideapad slim 3
   Ryzen 7 7730 u
   Radeon Graphics card
   512GB SSD
Came With Windows 11 Home
I tried:

I Deleted the system and installed it again.
I changed the value of /etc/default/grub RUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT.
I disabled USB suspending.
I installed another kernel version.
I disabled intel_usbt.
I asked Chat_GPT and researched the problem.

